# Restructuring code in two .bat files

Tags: csv, batch-file, text, vbscript

I have developed a program (1) coded in batch named `info.bat`:

- Store information about a computer,
- Manipulates information and outputs details to `%ComputerName%.csv` file.
- Then a `.vbs` file (2) is called, and this outputs a list of installed programs to `%ComputerName%-programs.txt` file in the same directory as the `.csv` file.
- The batch file ends when the `.vbs` has finished, and user is shown a Cmd window ready for next command.

Next another program `StripSoftware.bat (3)` is manually started:

- It creates `%ComputerName%-programs-to-check.txt`,
- Adds OS version and `%ComputerName%`,
- Examines entries in `%ComputerName%-programs.txt`,
- Takes out unwanted matches (using findstr and switches),
- Removes empty lines,
- Sorts results ascending,
- Then puts them into `%ComputerName%-programs-to-check.txt`

Aim:

- I need to use the software entries (1 line per software name) in `%ComputerName%-programs-to-check.txt`, concatenate them together, then put them into the `software_needed` column in the `.csv` file.

Output:

- The output needed is a `.csv` file or preferably an `.xlsx` file with the following headers in the 1st row, and applicable information in the 2nd row.

.csv example:

```
v34,ID,Asset,Sys_Type,Model,NHC Asset,New Sys Type,New Model,New Sys Asset,Domain,DIR,Site,Team,Location,Post,Name,Postcode,Local Printers,Network Printers,Eth_MACs,Wifi_MACs,Phone_MAC,Software Needed,OTHER_ASSET,OS_VER,Hostname,Software_Notes,Other_Notes,IGEL_REC
,,ABCDEFG,PC,A123,,,,,XXXX,Unknown,,,,,,, , ,||"XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX"|"Disabled",,,Not Used,ABCDEFG,Win XP Pro,ABCDEFG,,,
```

Partial contents of `info.bat`:

```
@echo OFF
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 
SET file="%~dp0%computername%.csv"
If Exist %file% Del %file%
echo %Version_tool%,ID,Asset,Sys_Type,Model,NHC Asset,New Sys Type,New Model,New Sys Asset,Domain,DIR,Site,Team,Location,Post,Name,Postcode,Local Printers,Network Printers,Eth_MACs,Wifi_MACs,Phone_MAC,Software Needed,OTHER_ASSET,OS_VER,Hostname,Software_Notes,Other_Notes,IGEL_REC>>%file%
rem  ========= Other code =========
echo ,%ID%,%serialnumber%,PC,%model%,,,,,%userdomain%,Unknown,,,,,,,%Local_Printers%,!network_printers!,!Eth_MACs!,!Wifi_MACs!,!Phone_MACs!,Not Used,%system%,%osname%,%Hostname%,,,%IGEL REC%>> %file%

SET file2="%~dp0%computername%-programs.txt"
If Exist %file2% Del %file2%
start /b cmd /k "cscript //nologo programs_02.vbs >> %file2%"
echo Batch Tool should finish in a few seconds ...
```

Contents of `.vbs` file:

```
Const HKLM = &H80000002 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE 
strComputer = "." 
strKey = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" 
strEntry1a = "DisplayName" 
strEntry1b = "QuietDisplayName" 
strEntry2 = "InstallDate" 
strEntry3 = "VersionMajor" 
strEntry4 = "VersionMinor" 
strEntry5 = "EstimatedSize" 

Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts://" & strComputer & "/root/default:StdRegProv") 
objReg.EnumKey HKLM, strKey, arrSubkeys 
WScript.Echo "Installed Applications" & VbCrLf 
For Each strSubkey In arrSubkeys 
  intRet1 = objReg.GetStringValue(HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, strEntry1a, strValue1) 
  If intRet1 <> 0 Then 
objReg.GetStringValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, strEntry1b, strValue1 
End If 
If strValue1 <> "" Then 
  WScript.Echo VbCrLf & strValue1 
End If 
objReg.GetStringValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, strEntry2, strValue2 
If strValue2 <> "" Then 
  'WScript.Echo "Install Date: " & strValue2 
End If 
objReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, strEntry3, intValue3 
objReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, strEntry4, intValue4 
If intValue3 <> "" Then 
   WScript.Echo "Version: " & intValue3 & "." & intValue4 
End If 
objReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, strEntry5, intValue5 
If intValue5 <> "" Then 
  'WScript.Echo "Estimated Size: " & Round(intValue5/1024, 3) & " megabytes" 
End If 
Next
```

Problem:

- With current way the code is structured `info.bat` creates `.csv` file before the `.txt` files are created and values for `Software_Needed` (eg `Adobe Flash | Hotfix for Windows`) is available in `%ComputerName%-programs-to-check.txt`. Hence difficult to then update the `.csv` with the value for `Software_Needed` on the second row.

Proposed solution: (*)

- I'm beginning to think the `.vbs` file should be called first to create `%ComputerName%-programs.txt` in the first `.bat` file, then in a second `.bat` file have the functionality in `StripSoftware.bat` to create `%ComputerName%-programs-to-check.txt`, and then use that and other information to create `%ComputerName%.csv`

Questions:

1) Would appreciate peoples thoughts, comments and views on the Proposed Solution

2) Suggestions as to better solutions than the proposed Solution.

Answer (score -1):

It's unclear what you want. This is a standard post of mine. Then I'll show you something.

Start - All Programs - Accessories - Right click Command Prompt and choose Run As Administrator. Type (or copy and paste by right clicking in the Command Prompt window and choosing Paste). Type for table format

```
wmic /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsInstaller.html" product get /format:htable
```

or in a form format

```
wmic /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsInstaller.html" product get /format:hform
```

It will create a html file on the desktop.

**Note**

This is not a full list. This is only products installed with Windows Installer. There is no feature for everything.

However as I said in my previous post nearly everything is listed in the registry.

So to see it in a command prompt

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s
```

or in a file

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s>"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsUninstall.txt"
```

To see it in notepad in a different format

Click Start - All Programs - Accessories - Right click Command Prompt and choose Run As Administrator. Type Regedit and navigate to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Right click the Uninstall key and choose Export. If you save as a reg file (there is also text file, they are slightly different text formats) you need to right click the file and choose Edit to view it.

**To view Windows Updates**

```
wmic /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsUpdate.html" qfe  get /format:htable
```

Here is a VBS script that get installed programs, sorts, and filters.

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set wshshell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout

ComputerName=WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Computername%")

'Build database with Computername and Softwarename

    With rs
        .Fields.Append "ComputerName", 201, 5000 

        .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
        .Open

        'Get list installed programs

        Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Product")

        'Add to database

        For Each objItem in colItems
            .AddNew
            .Fields("ComputerName").value = ComputerName
            .Fields("Txt").value = objItem.Name
            .UpDate
        Next
        'Sort Database on software name

        'Sort and filter it - Softwarename acending (Txt) and filter only those starting M

        .Sort = "Txt ASC"
        .Filter = "Txt like 'm*'"

        'write out to a CSV

        Do While not .EOF
            Outp.writeline .Fields("ComputerName").Value & "," & .Fields("Txt").Value

            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
```

To use

```
cscript //nologo <path to vbs file> > OUTPUTFILE
```

This is the output

```
SERENITY,Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1
SERENITY,Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1
SERENITY,Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile
SERENITY,Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended
SERENITY,Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit 5.0
SERENITY,Microsoft Application Error Reporting
SERENITY,Microsoft Calculator Plus
SERENITY,Microsoft Device Emulator version 3.0 - ENU
SERENITY,Microsoft Document Explorer 2005
SERENITY,Microsoft Filter Pack 1.0
SERENITY,Microsoft LifeCam
SERENITY,Microsoft Mathematics
SERENITY,Microsoft Network Monitor 3.0
SERENITY,Microsoft Office XP Professional
SERENITY,Microsoft OpenType Font File Properties Extension
SERENITY,Microsoft Search Enhancement Pack
```

So there are three places where you can discard items. In the WMI `select`.

```
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Product where Name='Microsoft LifeCam'")
```

And also in the filter as shown above using similar syntax.

Also while writing it back you can compare it then and not write the ones you don't want.

Comment: What is not clear in my questions? Let me know and I can provide more information and / or update the questions.

Comment: The output you desire, I had to guess. Your question described your programs general interaction.

Comment: I've updated the question. Please advise after rereading if there is anything else you need clarifying.

Comment: But what output do you want, not how you should think it should be generated, but what you want.

Comment: I've added output I need along with a .csv example, and also some of the code in the `info.bat` file and `.vbs` file

Comment: `wmic product get name, caption, Installdate, version /format:csv >> ProductList.txt` Size is some wierd guess based on word matching of start menu items.

Comment: when run in a cmd prompt that gives an error of "Invalid XSL format (or) file name." However  `wmic product get name, caption, Installdate, version` doesn't give an error.

Comment: There are some Windows version differences. However I gave you a VBScript that does everything if you modify it as shown.

Comment: Thank you for the vbscript. However my question is not asking for a vbscript, instead it is asking primarily for advice about the order items are run in to get the specified .csv file in ".csv example", not the one you specify using `wmic` since the output is different - ie your current answer is not tailored to my question.